# What does tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.texts_to_matrix do?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Please explain what [tokenizer.texts_to_matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#texts_to_matrix) does and what the result is?

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")

sentences = [text]
print(sentences)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(sentences)
print(word_index)
print(sequences)
print(matrix)
---
['The fool doth think he is wise, but the wise man knows himself to be a fool.']

# word_index
{'<OOV>': 1, 'the': 2, 'fool': 3, 'wise': 4, 'doth': 5, 'think': 6, 'he': 7, 'is': 8, 'but': 9, 'man': 10, 'knows': 11, 'himself': 12, 'to': 13, 'be': 14, 'a': 15}

# sequences
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9, 2, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 3]]

# matrix
[[0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the binary mode (default mode), it indicates which words from learnt vocabulary are in the input texts. You have trained your tokenizer on

```
['The fool doth think he is wise, but the wise man knows himself to be a fool.']
```

So when you convert the same text to a matrix, it will have all words (indicated by `1`) except `OOV`  - because all words are known - hence position at 1 of result vector is 0 (see `word_index`, and 0 is always 0 since words are enumerated starting from 1

**Some examples**

```py
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['foo'])
# only OOV in this one text
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.]])
```

```py
 tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['he he'])
# known word, twice (does not matter how often)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.]])
```

```py
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['the fool'])
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.]])
```

**Other mods**

Other mods are more clear

- *count* - How many times a word from vocabulary was in the text

```py
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['He, he the fool'], mode="count")
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.]])
```

- *freq* - count with sum normalized to 1.0

```py
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['he he the fool'], mode="freq")
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ,
        0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

- [*tfidf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

```py
tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(['he he the fool'], mode="tfidf")
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.84729786, 0.84729786, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.43459998, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        ]])
```